# When i compile i keep getting build failed? I am using Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I don't know why this won't work. I don't know if it have to do with passing though the function or the way I created my variables. But I have to use the `toDigit` function for my homework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int toDigit(char &);

int main(){
    int number;
    char isbn;

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("numbers.txt");

    while (inputFile >> isbn) {
        number = toDigit(isbn);
        cout << number << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

int toDigit(char ch){
    return ch - '0';
}
```

Comment: Read your compiler's error message. Then act on it.

Comment: toDigit has 2 different signatures. Your prototype does not match your implementation.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "toDigit(char&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                           this is the only error i get

Comment: how do i fix my prototype

Comment: Make it the same as your implementation.

Comment: @Zach, the other comments have already told you want to change.  The function definition has to match the function declaration.

Comment: This is your prototype (and what needs to be changed): `int toDigit(char &);`

Comment: i don't know what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you declare toDigit to be

```
 int toDigit(char &);
```

which would be read as this: a function returning an int that takes one argument that is *a reference* to a char.

Then, later you define this function like this:

```
int toDigit(char ch){
    return ch - '0';
}
```

which could be read like this: a function returning an int that takes one argument that is a char.

Do you see the difference? Hint: *a reference*.

In c++, definitions need to be the same as declarations, so you need to make them the same.

EITHER:

Make the declaration

```
 int toDigit(char );
 //               ^^ no &
```

OR

make the definition

```
int toDigit(char & ch){
//               ^^ & added
    return ch - '0';
}
```

In this case, the first option makes more sense because you don't need read access the the character and chars are efficient to copy, so a copy would be fine.